# Базовый код на Python работает очень долго из-за ввода больших чисел

Tags: python

Задачка: Посчитать сумму чисел от 1 до N. Значение N по модулю не превышает 10^9.

При вводе +-10^9 зависает. При вводе +-10^8 работает, но долго. Как исправить?

Код:

```
n = int(input())

summa = 0

if n >= 0:
    while n >= 1:
        summa += n
        n -= 1

elif n < 0:
    while n <= 1:
        summa += n
        n += 1

print(summa)
```

Comment: А какая цель этого всего? Если просто посчитать, то ведь есть формула, по которой сумма арифметической прогрессии считается без цикла. А если цикл обязателен, то есть всякие другие приколы, например библиотека Numba.

Comment: `sum(range(1, N+1))`

Comment: @CrazyElf а есть формула для отрицательных чисел?

Comment: @andreymal Не знаю )  Должна быть, надо гуглить )  Стоп, но ведь это тоже самое что для положительных, только в конце надо 1 будет прибавить

Comment: Решение в одну строку: `print((lambda n: ((abs(n) * (abs(n) + 1)) // 2) * (-1 if n < 0 else 1) + (1 if n <= 0 else 0))(int(input())))`

Comment: @CrazyElf прибавить 1 это костыль для частного случая) А вот бы иметь формулу подсчёта последовательности от произвольного M до произвольного N с произвольными знаками, тут прибавлением 1 уже не выкрутиться

Comment: @andreymal это по какой формуле решение?

Comment: @andreymal Формула для суммы арифм. прогрессии работает для любых знаков начала и конца

Comment: @Александр по классической https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-1-%D0%B4%D0%BE-N

Comment: @MBo а и правда, видимо мне пора пробежаться по школьным учебникам математики))

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. как отметить лучший ответ?

Comment: Александр чтобы отметить лучший ответ, нужно, чтоб вам его дали. а @andreymal , как обычно, скорее всего лень.

Answer (score 2):

```
from math import ceil

def ariphm_sum(start, stop, step=1):
    """ Сумма арифметической прогрессии
        Аргументы аналогичны функции range, т.е. [start, stop) с шагом step

    """
    n = ceil((stop - start) / step)
    return (start + step*(n-1)/2) * n

assert ariphm_sum(1, 101) == 5050
assert ariphm_sum(-100, 0) == -5050
assert ariphm_sum(-100, 101) == 0
assert ariphm_sum(1, 8, 2) == 16
assert ariphm_sum(1, 10, 2) == 25
assert ariphm_sum(-3, 10, 2) == 21
assert ariphm_sum(-10**8, 10**8+2) == 100000001
```